# Store value from SELECT statement into variable

Tags: php, mysql

How can i store the value from a SELECT MySQL statement into a PHP variable?
for example:

```
$myvariable = SELECT * FROM X WHERE id = X
```

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the manual of the database wrapper of your choice, or one of the many available tutorials. At the very least, specify what database library you want to (or can) use so people can point you in the right direction. If you're unsure about which wrapper to use, one good idea is PDO. A good tutorial on PDO is [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Comment: Don't ask "how" questions when you haven't even tried it.

Comment: I have tried and I have searched Google so why dont you try to be helpful.

Comment: That way you are storing the statement (though badly written, use quotes or double quotes) into the variable. Then you have to actually execute the query. And then you can retrieve its results.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look at the php manual for the mysql/mysqli wrapper functions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

If the code you provided was written with proper syntax (you need single/double quotes around string literals in php) your variable would contain the sql query string.  You need to send that to the database via some kind of wrapper.

You may wont to search around for some general php and php/mysql tutorials.